# Updating failure - Gitlab CE 7.0.0 - Ubuntu 12.04 - Package installation

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Upgrading Gitlab CE 7.0.0 to latest version using the package at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/precise/gitlab-ce_8.12.4-ce.0_amd64.deb failed. 
I have followed [this guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update/README.md#updating-from-gitlab-66-and-higher-to-710-or-newer).

Please see below the log entries below after runnnig `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check SANITIZE=true.`

```
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 3.6.1 ? ... OK (3.6.1)
Repo base directory exists?
default... yes
Repo storage directories are symlinks?
default... no
Repo paths owned by git:git?
default... yes
Repo paths access is drwxrws---?
default... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column projects.pending_delete does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."pending_de...
                                              ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."pending_delete" = 'f'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:356:in `select'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:270:in `execute_simple_calculation'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:227:in `perform_calculation'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:133:in `calculate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:48:in `count'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:13:in `count'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:469:in `check_repos_hooks_directory_is_link'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:348:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column projects.pending_delete does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."pending_de...
                                              ^
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:356:in `select'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:270:in `execute_simple_calculation'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:227:in `perform_calculation'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:133:in `calculate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:48:in `count'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:13:in `count'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:469:in `check_repos_hooks_directory_is_link'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:348:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the environment info run with `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`

```
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.3.1p112
Gem Version:    2.6.6
Bundler Version:1.13.1
Rake Version:   10.5.0
Sidekiq Version:4.1.4
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'pending_delete' for Project.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:28:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:169:in `initialize_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:251:in `block in build_record'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:465:in `block in initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:283:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/default_value_for-3.0.2/lib/default_value_for.rb:142:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:463:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:141:in `build_association'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:250:in `build_record'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `build'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:259:in `build'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/info.rake:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `pending_delete=' for #<Project:0x00000007337b90>
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:28:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:169:in `initialize_attributes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:251:in `block in build_record'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:465:in `block in initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:283:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/default_value_for-3.0.2/lib/default_value_for.rb:142:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:463:in `initialize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:141:in `build_association'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:250:in `build_record'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `build'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:259:in `build'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/info.rake:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:env:info
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me complete this upgrade:

1. Upgrade to 7.10 using the package at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/el/6/gitlab-ce-7.10.0~omnibus-1.x86_64.rpm
2. Then update to latest version: `curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash` followed by `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce`